# Why I cannot create new xcode project here?

Tags: xcode8, macos-sierra

[image]

In here I cannot go forward. I'm newer to the iOS and Xcode. So i can't get what's the problem,why 'Next' is disable.

Comment: because you are missing an organization identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the organization identifier.

There is an example below that field:
Something like: com.yourcompany

Answer (score 1):

Add your Organization Identifier and you should be able to create a project